# R, fetching data and storing excel/csv files as separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, screen-scraping, economics

I am trying to programmatically retrieve and store data in (named) data frames with appropriate column names etc. My for loop isn't working to retrieve the data and store it in an appropriately named dataframe (see: pg$Df_names). Cheers for all your help. The fixed code is available for reference in iv) - Please offer any improvements you may have.

```
necessary_packages <- c("readr", "readxl", "xlsx","stringr", "dplyr", "tidyr", "rvest", "xml2","SnowballC", "httr", "Rcurl", "rvest")

new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% 
                                       installed.packages()[,"Package"])]

if(length(new_packages)) install.packages(new_packages)

lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

### i)Create a data frame containing all of urls of RBA data, and dataframe names:

```
Base_URL <- "http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/"
```

### ii)Read the html into R parse through the text, for any csv or excel files:

```
pg <- as.data.frame((html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(Base_URL), "a"), "href")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
file_types <- c(".xls", ".csv", ".xlsx")
pg <- as.data.frame(paste0(Base_URL, gsub("/statistics/tables/",
                                            "", 
                                            unique(grep(paste(file_types, collapse = "|"), 
                                                        pg[,1], value = TRUE)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(pg) <- "urls"
```

### iii)Store a character vector of dataframe names:

```
pg$Df_names <- gsub("\\-|[[:punct:]]", "_", 
                    gsub("\\..*",
                    "",
                    sapply(strsplit(pg$urls, split= "\\/"), function(x){x[length(x)]})))
```

### iv)Store each excel file as a separate dataframe named by each element of the character vector:

```
df_names_list <- NULL
files_to_remove <- NULL
df_list <- list()
h = 1
i = 1
j = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(pg)) {
  if (length(grep(".xls", pg$urls[i])) > 0) {
    tryit <- try(GET(pg$urls[i], write_disk(tf <-
                                              tempfile(fileext = ".xls"), overwrite = TRUE)))
    if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
      i <- i + 1
    } else{
      GET(pg$urls[i], write_disk(tf <-
                                   tempfile(fileext = ".xls"), overwrite = TRUE))
      shiet <- excel_sheets(tf)[which(
        excel_sheets(tf) != "Summary" &
          excel_sheets(tf) != "Notes" &
          excel_sheets(tf) != "Series breaks"
      )]
    }
    for (j in 1:length(shiet)) {
      tryit <- try(tmp1 <-
                     as.data.frame(read_xls(tf, sheet = shiet[j], col_names = FALSE)))
      if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
        j <- j + 1
      } else{
        tmp1 <-
          as.data.frame(read_xls(tf, sheet = shiet[j], col_names = FALSE))
      }
      if (ncol(tmp1) > 2) {
        tryit <- try(X <- as.data.frame(read_xls(
          gsub('[\\]', '\\/', tf),
          skip = 11,
          col_names = FALSE,
          sheet = shiet[j]
        )))
        if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
          j <- j + 1
        } else{
          X <- as.data.frame(read_xls(
            gsub('[\\]', '\\/', tf),
            skip = 11,
            col_names = FALSE,
            sheet = shiet[j]
          ))
        }
        colnames(X) <- c("Date",
                         c(trimws(
                           gsub(
                             "for series breaks.*|[[:punct:]]| |Seenot",
                             "",
                             tools::toTitleCase(wordStem(tmp1[2, 2:ncol(tmp1)],
                                                         language = "porter"))
                           ),
                           which = c("both", "left", "right")
                         )))
        df_list[[h]] <- X
        df_names_list <-
          c(df_names_list, gsub(" ", "_", trimws(
            paste0(pg$Df_names[i], "_", shiet[j]),
            which = c("both", "left", "right")
          )))
        h <- h + 1
      } else{
        rm(tmp1)
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
  } else if (length(grep(".xslx", pg$urls[i])) > 0) {
    tryit <- try(GET(pg$urls[i], write_disk(tf <-
                                              tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)))
    if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
      i <- i + 1
    } else{
      GET(pg$urls[i], write_disk(tf <-
                                   tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE))
      shiet <- excel_sheets(tf)[which(
        excel_sheets(tf) != "Summary" &
          excel_sheets(tf) != "Notes" &
          excel_sheets(tf) != "Series breaks"
      )]
    }
    for (j in 1:length(shiet)) {
      tryit <- try(tmp1 <-
                     as.data.frame(read_xlsx(tf, sheet = shiet[j], col_names = FALSE)))
      if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
        j <- j + 1
      } else{
        tmp1 <-
          as.data.frame(read_xlsx(tf, sheet = shiet[j], col_names = FALSE))
      }
      if (ncol(tmp1) > 2) {
        tryit <- try(X <- as.data.frame(read_xlsx(
          gsub('[\\]', '\\/', tf),
          skip = 11,
          col_names = FALSE,
          sheet = shiet[j]
        )))
        if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
          j <- j + 1
        } else{
          X <- as.data.frame(read_xlsx(
            gsub('[\\]', '\\/', tf),
            skip = 11,
            col_names = FALSE,
            sheet = shiet[j]
          ))
        }
        colnames(X) <- c("Date",
                         c(trimws(
                           gsub(
                             "for series breaks.*|[[:punct:]]| |Seenot",
                             "",
                             tools::toTitleCase(wordStem(tmp1[2, 2:ncol(tmp1)],
                                                         language = "porter"))
                           ),
                           which = c("both", "left", "right")
                         )))
        df_list[[h]] <- X
        df_names_list <-
          c(df_names_list, gsub(" ", "_", trimws(
            paste0(pg$Df_names[i], "_", shiet[j]),
            which = c("both", "left", "right")
          )))
        h <- h + 1
      } else{
        rm(tmp1)
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
  } else if (length(grep(".csv", pg$urls[i])) > 0) {
    tryit <- try(X <- as.data.frame(read.csv(pg$urls[i],
                                             skip = 11,
                                             header = FALSE)))
    if (inherits(tryit, "try-error")) {
      i <- i + 1
    } else {
      X <- as.data.frame(read.csv(pg$urls[i],
                                  skip = 11,
                                  header = FALSE))
    }
    tmp1 <- as.data.frame(read.csv(pg$urls[i]))
    if (ncol(tmp1) >= 2) {
      colnames(X) <- c("Date",
                       c(trimws(
                         gsub(
                           "for series breaks.*|[[:punct:]]| |Seenot",
                           "",
                           tools::toTitleCase(wordStem(tmp1[2, 2:ncol(tmp1)],
                                                       language = "porter"))
                         ),
                         which = c("both", "left", "right")
                       )))
      df_list[[h]] <- X
      df_names_list <-
        c(df_names_list, gsub(" ", "_", trimws(
          pg$Df_names[i],
          which = c("both", "left", "right")
        )))
      h <- h + 1

    } else{
      rm(tmp1)
      j <- j + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue is that you use `read_xls` to read online files. Another thing is that `setNames(pg$Df_names[i]) <- ...` isn't going to work. However, the latter thing is also not a great practice. Perhaps a list `l` with elements named `pg$Df_names` and being data frames would also work?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it now works I will post the code above.